# different <driver-class> for same datasource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource

I'm writing a class reading information from a database, which could be oracle or mysql.
I'm using javax.sql.DataSource and code like:

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:personalDS");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

After that i need to execute some query, but they must be different in case i use oracle or mysql ds. the xml file will contains:

```
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
```

or

```
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
```

i would like to write something like

```
if (ds.getDriver().contains("mysql") {...}
else if (ds.getDriver().contasins("Oracle") {...}
```

but the method getDriver does not exist .... also from context i don't understand how 'get' the driver-class property of my resource.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DatabaseMetaData class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

I'm not sure if all vendors implement this, but this is the intent for this class. You can get a handle to it from the underlying connection object.

```
dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData()
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to check for the data source class. AFAIK every major driver has its own DataSource implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some switch in some property file, or you can parse the initial xml file containing driver-class-name to discover what db is used